# Jetpack Compose share Viewmodel between Activity and Composables

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have followed this tutorial to get the basic regarding `ViewModel` and `Jetpack Compose`:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state#0

In the above tutorial, in section 6 is shown the next `Composable` function which seems to initialize the `ViewModel` locally:

```
@Composable
fun GameScreen(
   gameViewModel: GameViewModel = viewModel()
) {
   // ...
}
```

Above approach is ok for the tutorial example as all the app logic resides in the `ViewModel`. The thing is that my app also needs to access the `ViewModel` (call some methods) from my `MainActivity` as my app needs to create and bind a custom process in the background from the `MainActivity` scope and the `ViewModel` needs to be updated based on the service status (started, stopped, events...) in order to consequently have the UI updated.

Is it right to create and bind the service form the `MainActivity`? Is it right to share the `ViewModel` between the `MainActivity` and the `Composable` functions? Which is the right way to do it? Initialize the `ViewModel` in the `MainActivity` and then pass it to all the `Composable` function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its common to share view models and the right way to manage shared state

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val gameViewModel: GameViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp(gameViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And now a question that I have added lately to my post. Is it right to create and bind the service form the MainActivity? or should it be done in the ViewModel (using AndroidViewModel() instead of ViewModel())